# How to export the all intermediate certs including root certificates using keytool only

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am Trying to configure SSL and got the .pfx file from server team.
The Certificate chain length: 2

When i am trying to export the certificate chain using keytool, only the first certificate is exported.

Trying to figure out if there is any other parameters i am missing while issuing keytool command.

the commands I used are:

1) converting to JKS as alias name is not supported with pfx

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore "serverauth.pfx" -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore "serverauth.jks"
```

2) Tried to Export certificates using the below.

```
keytool -export -alias 1 -keystore "serverauth.jks" -rfc -file "authclient.cert"
```

But above command generates only first cert.

If i remove entire alias option, getting error

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <1> does not exist
```

Is there any other process.

Comment: You may have to export each cert in the signing chain individually. What does `keytool -list` show for the entries in the .pfx file?

Comment: @Andrew It listed two certificates.. Alias name: 1
Creation date: May 10, 2015
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 2
Certificate[1]: ......  Certificate[2]:.....

Comment: Could you post that full `keytool -list` output in the question itself, so we can see the details?

Answer (score 15):

You could do (exemple with java cacert):

```
for cert in `keytool -list -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit | grep trustedCertEntry | grep -Eo "^[^,]*"`;do
    `keytool -exportcert -keystore cacerts -alias $cert -file ${cert}.crt <<< $'changeit'`
done
```

That will export all cert in a separated .crt file

Comment: Needs small change due to whitespace in aliases: precede with IFS=$'\n' and quote the -alias argument.  You should use -cacert parameter to avoid the warning.  Also -storepass parameter instead of <<< may speed things up

Answer (score 14):

This works in Java 8 to export the whole certificate chain to a file:

```
keytool -list -alias yourcert -keystore /path/to/keystore -rfc
```

Same format as export except it dumps the whole chain. You lose out on the -file option, but you can simply redirect to a file using `>`

Comment: This did not work on my Java 8. It exported the end-entity certificate, only:  
java version "1.8.0_144"  
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)  
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)

Answer (score 12):

```
keytool -list -rfc -keystore serverauth.jks
```

This will output all the certs in a single stream. If you wanted to split them into separate files, you'd have more work to do.

Comment: This did not work on my Java 8. It exported the end-entity certificate, only:  
java version "1.8.0_144"  
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)  
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)