# Secure connection failed to a java server

Tags: java, ssl

I tried to secure the connection to my java server, after downloading a certificate(certificate.crt) and adding it to the keystore (keystore.jks) my server run normally and read the certificate.But if I want to consume a service via https://123.456.88.99:1010/myService from the navigator(firefox) I get a PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.ps : http://123.456.88.99:1010/myService works and consume the service and retrieve data also by using firefox, I think its a problem of private key that the navigator don't get, I really need help, thank you
ps if I try to use a certificate that I create using keytool it works

> ```
> private void startHttpsServer(RestFactory factory, int port, int minWorkers, int maxWorkers, int socketTimeoutMS, 
>           boolean keepConnection, boolean ignoreContentLength, boolean debug, Compression compression, boolean useClassicServer, boolean requireCertificate) throws Exception {
>         String alias = "server-alias";
>         String pwd = "changeit";
>         char [] storepass = pwd.toCharArray();
>         String keystoreName = "c:\\keystore.jks";
>         FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(keystoreName);
>         KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
>         keystore.load(in, storepass);
>         Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);
>         Log.debug("the certification is here : " + cert);
>         KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
>         char [] keypass = pwd.toCharArray();
>         kmf.init(keystore, keypass);
>         TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
>         tmf.init(keystore);
>         SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
>         sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
>         SSLEngine engine = sslContext.createSSLEngine();
>         engine.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[] {"TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
>                 "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
>                 "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
>                 "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"});
>         SSLParameters defaultSSLParameters = sslContext.getDefaultSSLParameters();
>         engine.setSSLParameters(defaultSSLParameters);             
>         HttpsRestServer server = new HttpsRestServer(factory, port, minWorkers, maxWorkers, debug, compression, keystore, keypass, false); 
>         server.addCleaner(new CleanupListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void cleanup(CleanupEvent event) {
>                 Database.disconnectAllThreadConnections(event.thread, false);
>             }
>         });
>         this.servers.add(server);
>         log.info("Starting classic HTTPS replication server on port " + port);
>         server.start();
>     log.info("Secure XML replication server started on port " + port);
> }
> ```

Comment: You connect through the IP address. But an SSL certificate is typically issued to a Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) such as "https://www.example.com".  If your SSL certificat should not be explicitely issued for the IP address instead of a domain name, connecting through the IP address will always lead to the mentioned error. You have to use the Common Name that is specified in your Certificate for connecting to your server.

Comment: that's right but why when I create a certificate using keytool.exe and the I add it to my truststore it works or on the certificate that I create I do not mention any IP address

Comment: You wrote "when I add it to my trusttore it works". So you also try to connect through a Java application? If the answer should be yes, are you sure that your java client is not using a dummy HostnameVerifier?

Comment: no I tried to connect just using an url on the browser.if I use keytool (keytool -genkey ..) and then export the certificate from it and import it it to the trust store, and I try to connect from a navigator I can retrieve data.But if I add a signed certificate to the trust store it doesn't work, on the navigator I get "Secure connection failed"

Comment: If you export the signed certificate you have to make sure that the browser also trusts your root certificate, resp. every certificate in between. You have to export the complete certificate chain. Following question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30091942/how-to-export-the-all-intermediate-certs-including-root-certificates-using-keyto